# How to prevent VLC player from resizing window when I click on playlist

Tags: vlc-media-player

I want VLC player to not resize it's window when I click on playlist button.
In both fullscreen and normal mode.

There used to be a settings for this, but I can't find it.

It's really annoying for 2 reasons:

1. visually it jumps abruptly
2. when I want to switch back to video I need to move my mouse again to find that same button.

PS.
I thought maybe it's connected to "automatically resize window to video size", but even when disabled it still changes size when I click on playlist.
I want to keep "automatically resize window to video size" and turn on don't resize when I click on playlist.

Answer (score 4):

It's related to "automatically resize window to video size", but you apparently need to restart the application in order to have this work. So, what I did was uncheck this under "tools>interface" and restart the app. It worked after this.

Answer (score 2):

Under `Tools` `->` `Preferences` `->` `Interface`: uncheck `Integrate video in interface`. This way you can conveniently place the interface relative to the video window, which is not resized and your point `1.` should be solved.

Point `2.`: you don't need to use the mouse at all. Switch from the video to the interface by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and open the playlist with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Select the desired playlist entry with the arrows and the enter key, or cycle from the video window with <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I don't like to have 2 windows when I could have one. It adds too many windows to alt tab through. I am not just watching a video, I am coding along and testing what I have done in browser or googling documentation. Or sometimes, after big dinner, I lay on my couch and I only have mouse available to control VLC and I code along on my laptop. Upvoting this anyway cause it does work, it's just not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> Tools -> Preferences -> Video

and change the Display device to "Display" instead of "Default".
Try this, and post your comments. Sorry if doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was an oversized video window, I simply went back to default VLC skin. 
"Tools > Preferences (Ctrl+P) > Interface tab > Use native style" ...custom skin caused an oversized window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools -> preferences -> video and change the Display device to display instead of Default. Try this and post your comments. Sorry if doesn't work for you.

Thanks,
Your Friend

[VLC Settings Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50JeI.jpg)